# QSqlQuery very slow in Qt5 sometimes

Tags: sqlite, qt5, qsqldatabase

I develop application based on Qt5. In my application I use sqlite3 database. And then I found one problem that the sqlite3 QSqlQuery.next() is very slow when my app first launch.

Comment: This can depend on the hardware, the software (OS, drivers, VM, SQLite version), the database schema, and the actual query.

Comment: Check if your CPU (or a core) is busy and what process eats up the CPU time.

Comment: Use a profiler to find the bottlenecks; just because it happens while executing a SQL query it doesn't mean it's the query. However this may well be the case if you've got changing query parameters and insufficient indexes or other suboptimal stuff in your query; you didn't provide enough details to point out something.